# couchdb _find security, filtering _find returned results

Tags: couchdb

I know that we can define a validation function for updates in replication. But what about find/select queries?

I am wondering if is it possible to put mandatory filter to all `_find` queries eg:
filter password field from person documents? or put automatic filter to show only that user's documents.I don't want a user be able to see other user's documents in the same collection.

Is it possible to put a java api in this regard?

Comment: CouchDB and Couchbase are two different things. Which one are you using?

Comment: preferably CouchDB otherwise Couchbase.I need their sync replication logic with pouchdb .

Comment: Please ask one question for each database technology. CouchDB and Couchbase are entirely different pieces of software, and as such, an answer to one will be completely irrelevant to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Couchbase, so I'll answer the question from the Couchbase angle.

Couchbase 7.0 (currently available in Beta at time of writing) introduces [scopes and collections](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/7.0/learn/data/scopes-and-collections.html). One of the use cases for scopes is to support multi-tenancy.

You create multiple "scopes" within a bucket, then give each database user [access to only certain scopes](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/7.0/learn/data/scopes-and-collections.html#access-to-scopes-and-collections).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is a limitation of 1000 scopes per bucket.then we need to create a scope for each user. we may have 10m users . Because we want an offline first application,ideally we want to use automatic filtered replication , but we want to disable automatic querying/reading and do it through our java api.